# set an index-like attribute through LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Collection of an Item, in which I have a property called index. I want to set this property in some patter say (index++). How can I do that through LINQ (without using for  each). Below is the statement in which i am generating collection.

```
new ObservableCollection<EventSchedules>(
    EventsList.Where(v => v.EventStartDate.Date.Equals(selectedDay.Date)));
```

Comment: Could you be more specific please? What do you mean saying in a some patter say?

Comment: @Christos as I am creating a dynamic collection out of another, i want to access index of each item in XAML (WP8). since it is not possible I added an attribute called index. which I can't set while creating object, but can be set only when the item is added to list. I can do that iterating the Collection but I want something cleaner way like that of a LINQ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well,

```
someSequenceWithAnIndexProperty.Select((i, item) =>
    {
        item.Index = i;
        return item;
    });
```

but this is weak because it doesn't project anything and changes the input as a side effect, so instead.

```
foreach(var pair in someSequenceWithAnIndexProperty
        .Select((i, item) => new { Item = item, Index = i }))
{
    pair.Item.Index = pair.Index;
}

return someSequenceWithAnIndexProperty;
```

Comment: this returns  int not the same type

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, better?

Comment: yes, but i figured out this little later. also that I need to use KVP of index & item. since the current way will update the object which might be a member of another list

Comment: @ay89 not quite sure I understand but, you could use the `.ToList()` extension. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx

Answer (score 1):

One of the key tenants of Linq (which is really a key tenant of functional programming) is that data should be immutable - or at least as immutable *as possible*.

In this case - the correct "linq like" way to do things, would be to *projecting* into new objects, with updated values - not setting values.

This kind of thing is best done with imperative code - i.e. a for loop.